# Flutter - Objectbox generation additional options for non CamelCase

Tags: flutter, dart, generator, camelcasing, objectbox

When I run the generator in flutter, it will generate my objectbox.g.dart file as expected and works fine but I get 100's of lint warnings

> Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase.

I don't have my properties set with camel case, So I have properties like CustomerID, Billing_Address1 etc.

In my model files I have

> // ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names

which stops the linting warnings. I prefer this style for models.

I want the generated file to also have this added when rebuilt. It already adds

// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types

So my question is how can I default this also?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `analysis_options.yaml` to your project, e.g. with the following contents:

```yaml
linter:
  rules:
    non_constant_identifier_names: false
```

or

```yaml
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - lib/objectbox.g.dart
```

Comment: I am still fairly new to flutter, I cannot locate the analysis_options.yaml file. does this mean it is using some defaults?.
I just added this to the root and its worked. Thanks

Comment: Have a look here for more details: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options